# Dimension contains a member property with invalid name

Tags: sql-server

I'm currently doing my attribute relationships for each dimension in my cube. I've stumbled upon an error that I cant seem to fix. 
The error I'm getting when I'm processing after I've made my attribute relationships and hierarchies is:

```
Errors in the metadata manager. The 'DIM Item' dimension contains a member property with invalid name: 'Name' is one of the reserved words.
```

I understand why It gives my error, but I don't understand how to correct it. - It is correct that my dimension contains a member called 'name', but I cant seem to change the name of it the right place.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that it was kind of a bug.

The name of the attribute had the same name as an attribute in another dimension. Couldn't fix it by editing the name it self, i had to completely delete the dimension, load it up, and edit the name before i did the hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the column name  from your DWH, then regenerate your DSV and cube, then run.